# when is $g\circ f$ convex if $g$ is convex and piece-wise linear $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I wonder the following property hold but I am unable to prove it. Can anyone help me !

> Given functions $f,g: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. Assume that $f$ be piece-wise linear and g is convex/concave. What kind of conditions on function $f$ to make composition function $g\circ f$ is convex/concave?

Its easy to check if $f$ is linear with second derivative but here the problem is that function $f$ is not differentiable.

Comment: What have you tried? What have you in mind? Are there finitely many pieces? A simple **necessary** conditions is, that $g\circ f$ is continuous.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the question the way it's worded. After all, any conditions that you might suggest for $f$ are *sufficient* but not *necessary*. That said: have you read Boyd & Vandenberghe's _Convex Optimization_, particularly the section on convex functions? You'll have a very clear answer there.